# Extract values just after empty string with R

Tags: r

I managed to get those lines from 3 different .txt files. I used "grep" command to extract lines containing word "Boiling". However I just want the value (See result). So How can I use the grep command to extract all the values  after the empty string, and save only those value in a csv/excel file

```
[1] "  Boiling:                                      80 - 93 °C (176°F - 199.4 °"
[1] "  Boiling:                                      > 93.3 °C (> 199.94 °F) "
[1] "  Boiling:                                      80 - 93 °C (176° closed cup"
```

Result should look like (with the quotes removed):

```
80 - 93 °C (176°F - 199.4 °
> 93.3 °C (> 199.94 °F)
80 - 93 °C (176° closed cup
```

Below is my code

```
my_txt<-list.files("G:\\FlashPointTest\\Test2\\sdstotextorigin", 
                   pattern = ".txt$",full.names = TRUE,recursive = FALSE )

lst<-vector("list",length(my_txt))
names(lst)<-my_txt

for(i in 1:length(my_txt)){
  doc<-readLines(my_txt[i])
  doc<-doc[grepl("Boiling",doc)]
  lst[[my_txt[[i]]]]<-doc
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: regEx is the name of the game!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there a many many ways here are some: (try out what works the best with your full data)

data:

```
vec<-
c("Boiling:                                      80 - 93 °C (176°F - 199.4 °",
"  Boiling:                                      > 93.3 °C (> 199.94 °F) ",
"  Boiling:                                      80 - 93 °C (176° closed cup")

library(magrittr);library(stringr);
```

1:

```
vec %>% sub("Boiling:","",.) %>% trimws
```

2:

```
vec %>% stringr::str_extract("(\\d|>).*")
```

3:

```
vec %>% stringr::str_extract("(?<=\\s{5}).*$") %>% trimws
```

Comment: I have been able to use solution "vec %>% stringr::str_extract("(\\d|>).*")" and it now work perfectly. I was also able to export the result to a csv file. Thanks a lot for your support!

Answer (score 1):

```
gsub('.*?\\s{2,}', '', vec)
# [1] "80 - 93 °C (176°F - 199.4 °" "> 93.3 °C (> 199.94 °F) "   
# [3] "80 - 93 °C (176° closed cup"
```

With vec as in Andre's answer:

```
vec<-
c("Boiling:                                      80 - 93 °C (176°F - 199.4 °",
"  Boiling:                                      > 93.3 °C (> 199.94 °F) ",
"  Boiling:                                      80 - 93 °C (176° closed cup")
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers. I forgot to mention that this was for only 3 files and what you can see (" Boiling:    80-90 C ") is the output in R console from command line "lst[[my_txt[[i]]]]. I needed this for 1000 files with the output saved in a Excel/ csv file. Thanks

Comment: Edited to be more general than just the word "Boiling".